# How to Modify values in existing Json File?

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I have json file Called "addplace.json" whose contents are pasted below. Now I need to read above said json file and change the values for Latitude, longitutde ,name,phone,Address. So how would i do that , please advise me with sample java code.

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
  "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should try something first, there are tons of tutorials on doing what you ask. If you get stuck, then comeback and share your failing code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give us any examples? In its present form, this question isn't appropriate for SO.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a Maven project, using the Gson library; define your Location and Place classes; de-serialize from json; edit your data; and then re-serialize to json format? Which one of these steps are you able to perform?

Comment: @ NiVer  I have tried  and asking for an solution. Its my miss that i did `nt paste the piece of code here. Below is the snippet that i had tried.

Comment: File jsonFile=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//resources//"+addPlace_Payload.json);
 if(jsonFile.exists())
 {  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader();
      String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(jsonFile);
      JsonNode node = reader.readTree(jsonString);
      System.out.println(node.toString());
      ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
      objectNode.put("location.lat", "-55.8669710");
      objectNode.put("name", "Mysuru");
      System.out.println(node.toString());
 }

Comment: I was able to change the value of name from "Google Shoes!" to "Mysusru" but i was not able to access the lat an lng  present inside  location object and change their values.

Comment: @ Daniele, the project that i did was an maven project and  i have used the Restassured java apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry forgot delayed response.Below is the code that i used to read the json file at runtime , modify it and fire the modified json as part of post operation

```
public class Post_Ex3 extends BaseStepClass{



public Scenario scenario;

@Before
public void beforeTest(Scenario scenario)
{
    this.scenario =scenario;
}

@When("user changes the attributes values like name {string} , Salary {string} and age {string} in json payload file {string}")
public void user_changes_the_attributes_values_like_name_Salary_and_age_in_json_payload_file(String name, String salary, String age, String payloadfileName) {
    

    String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\JsonFiles\\"+payloadfileName;
    System.out.println("path : " +filepath);
    
    try {
        String jsonContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath))));
    
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonContents);
        
        System.out.println(" Post Payload Before changes: ");
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(4));
        
        //changing the value of name from tammy to balaji
        jsonObject.put("name", name);
        jsonObject.put("salary", salary);
        jsonObject.put("age", age);
                    
        System.out.println(" Post Payload after changes: ");
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(4));
        
        String payload = jsonObject.toString(4);
        
        
        scenario.write("Payload Passed along with post request");
        scenario.write(payload);
        
         // Add a header stating the Request body is a JSON
          httpRequest.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
          
        // Add the Json to the body of the request            
          httpRequest.body(jsonObject.toString(4));
          
             
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No file found in the path ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        
}


@When("user initiates post request with {string} endpoint")
public void user_initiates_post_request_with_endpoint(String string) {
              
     response = httpRequest.post("/create");
}



@Then("user should get an status code as {string} in post response")
public void user_should_get_an_status_code_as_in_post_response(String expectedStatusCode) {
   
    
       int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, Integer.parseInt(expectedStatusCode),"Failed due to Server issue -"+statusCode);
        Assert.assertNotNull(response.asString());
        System.out.println("Response :" + response.prettyPrint());
        
        System.out.println("Status Code :" + response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("Does Reponse contains 'tammy'? :" + response.asString().contains("tammy"));
        String name = response.jsonPath().get("data.name").toString();
        System.out.println(" name : " +name);
        System.out.println(" Salary value in response : " +response.jsonPath().get("data.salary").toString());
        
}
```

}